# dplyr mutate if else

Tags: r, dplyr

I need help to find the best way to convert the table below using the conditions:

**If...**

1. the data of the 1st column (plot number) and
2. the data of the 2st column (subplot number) and
3. the data of the 3rd column (trees) and
4. the name of the tree in the 4th column (tree_species) and
5. the data of the 5th column (stems)

are the SAME in different rows the new column dbh_equivalent will be result of the function:

```
=SQRT(dbc_cm - row1^2+dbc_cm-row2^2+...+dbc_cm- row n^2).
```

[image]

That is, in the table above the result would be:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide a reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: How did the value in the last column in the last row of your result become 21.5?